# Can you stop marketing messages on an iPhone X (e-sim)

Tags: iphone, esim

On Android, to avoid the marketing popup messages from the SIM Toolkit, I need to force stop it, and everytime I reboot, I need to force stop it again.

On iPhone X, with the e-sim, what happens to the popup marketing messages? Is it possible to avoid them?

Update: I'm talking about this:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75761/how-to-prevent-phone-operator-from-opening-spam-popups

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are asking. Do you currently receive SIM Toolkit messages on your iPhone or just your Android device?

Comment: Additionally who is your cellular carrier?

Comment: @drivec I'm in Brazil, some cellular carriers use the SIM Toolkit to show marketing messages. I use a dual ship Android phone with Vivo and Tim carriers

Comment: @TomBrito Have you tried blocking the numbers?

Comment: @DManokhin it's not about numbers. Check my update.

Comment: Disabling Flash Messages are same for a physical or eSim. There is no difference.

Comment: @JashJacob on Android 8, non rooted, there's no way to disable this spam messages. You can force stop the SIMTOOKIT, but it'll run again on restart.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are posting about Flash messages.  Depending on the carrier there may be a code that you can enter to disable them, you would need to contact them or their support for help with this.

You can also check the device settings.  Settings>Phone>Sim Applications (you may or may not have this menu option depending on your carrier).  From there you may have many entries that you can select on the choose to start/stop or deactivate.  [See this link for screen shots and more information.](https://www.geekdashboard.com/stop-flash-messages-iphone-and-ipad/)

Comment: In Brazil the carrier is not really there to help you, it's there to take your money by any ways it can. The SIM Toolkit app also don't have any options to disable the marketing messages. And recently the SIM Toolkit is restarting itself, even without I restarting my phone. I think the only way would be by rooting the Android system to take some control... I just don't know if I can trust my passwords to a rooted phone, but that's another question...